# Unexpected Spark behaviour when joining on union of literal columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've been using Spark (current version 2.1.0) for some time now, but ran into some strange behaviour.

Let's say you have two dataframes:

```
df_before = sparkSession.createDataFrame([('a', 4), ('b', 5)], ['A', 'B'])
df_after  = sparkSession.createDataFrame([('a', 6), ('b', 7)], ['A', 'B'])
```

We augment them with a column describing their origin (or something). In this case just a column that says before or after:

```
df_before = df_before.withColumn('C', lit('before'))
df_after = df_after.withColumn('C', lit('after'))
```

And put them together in one dataframe:

```
df_all = df_before.union(df_after)
```

Which gives us:

```
 A | B | C
---|---|------
 a | 4 | before
 b | 5 | before
 a | 6 | after
 b | 7 | after
```

Next we also happen to have a different dataframe:

```
data_other = [
  ('a', 'before', 10), 
  ('b', 'before', 11), 
  ('a', 'after', 12), 
  ('b', 'after', 13)
]

df_other = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data_other, ['A', 'C', 'D'])
```

If I then join the two straighforwardly:

```
df_all.join(df_other, ['A', 'C'])
```

I get:

```
 A | C      | B | D  
---|--------|---|----
 a | before | 4 | 10 
 b | before | 5 | 11 
 a | after  | 6 | 10 
 b | after  | 7 | 11
```

Which is different from what I expected:

```
 A | C      | B | D  
---|--------|---|----
 a | before | 4 | 10 
 b | before | 5 | 11 
 a | after  | 6 | 12 
 b | after  | 7 | 13
```

Can someone explain this behaviour? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution:
Upgrade Spark to 2.1.1 as bugfix [SPARK-19766](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19766) solves it.

If for some reason that option is not available, this is a workaround for 2.1.0:

Instead of:

```
 df_after = df_after.withColumn('C', lit('after'))
```

Use a udf to create the column:

```
 def my_lit(literal):
     def returnLiteral(x): return literal
     return udf(returnLiteral, StringType())

 df_after.withColumn('C', my_lit('after')(df_after['A']))
```